# Private network p2p files updates

Tags: windows, p2p, file-copying

all!

I'm currently working for a project involving deploying netbooks to the villages for educational purposes. Because of the slow connection (if there's any at all) there, it's hard to push content updates (basically synchronising files with server content).

We are thinking about zombie-like p2p updates, when someone from village comes to the city and updates his/her netbook. Then other netbooks from the village would get updates from the netbooks, which was updated in the city.

I would appreciate if you could guide me on existing solutions to this problem. I tried to google it, but found nothing.

Unfortunately we don't have programmers in our team, so we are looking for finished products. E.g. installing some program (utorrent) which would run on netbooks and check wifi network every 1 hour.

Villages do have wifi.

Thanks.

Comment: You're probably looking for file sync software - if you do a web search for that phrase, you'll find loads. You can do this via a script involving `rsync` - on Window it's called `Cwrsync`. The precise command to issue depends on what you want to sync with what, but it's quite easy to do even if you're not a programmmer - just requires a bit of research.

Comment: Just to add background for other readers, do you have a wifi router at "the villages"? It's easier to get netbooks to connect to each other via a router, rather than directly.

Comment: By which you mean they use a box with flashing lights and an aerial coming out of it? _Wifi_ is a general name for a wireless data technology, so _they have wifis_ doesn't explain how they connect their laptops together.

Comment: Sorry. Should've been more clear on that :))))

They have some kind of community centers, where they have access to internet. We have installed wifi routers there. Netbooks are part of 1 domain and connect to dchp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like there's no ready solution for p2p updates. We are thinking about using p2p tracker system instead.

Overall, seems like p2p is not the best option for updates, especially if content is sensitive.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Cwrsync](https://www.itefix.no/i2/cwrsync).

Answer (score 0):

Luke, I think I have a good solution for you.

uTorrent is a light-weight torrent client that will run well on these netbooks. Using RSS feeds you can have them automatically download updates i.e. join the update file swarm as soon as it is released.

You will not NEED to use a tracker, instead utilising DHT, however it would probably make things easier if you implemented something like `openbittorrent.com`'s tracker.

Hence the only step left to automate the updates is to have the update automatically execute. However if I am right it sounds like these content updates installation need only have them download to the correct directory, which would be something you specify when you're setting up the RSS feed to download from in uTorrent.